# Automatic Page Breaks using a JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, printing, jeditorpane

I'm using a JEditorPane to load some HTML content from a String so that I can print it. I load a HTML template and use String.format() to insert variables and other templates. I then call the print() function on a new JEditorPane.

That all works fine, but when it prints it does not properly paginate so that the elements are not trimmed off. I can get tables that are half on the bottom of one page, and half on the top of another page, with text split as well.

[image: screenshot]

I was wondering if anybody knew a solution to this, or if there is a better way to print HTML without using any not open-source libraries or default libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggesting to read [Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) tutorial, there is simple descriptions about [Printing a Multiple Page Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/set.html), a few usefull examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this
http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html

Or create your own custom pagination
http://java-sl.com/Pagination_In_JEditorPane.html

Comment: maybe stupid question what's happens by using your algoritm when paragraf(s) contains long text, or there is used some image as background

Comment: you can try:-) if the image is less than page widht/height it will be correctly moved to the next page.